# Three.js material alignment on scene

Tags: 3d, three.js, blender

I have a large material (sized 10x10 on Blender) and 10 other materials sized 1x1.

So, I put every small material on the X-axis on the large material. (x = -5, -4, -3, etc. x = 5).

The problem is the small materials aren't perfectly aligned on the big one.

On the very left, the small material is shifted by the right, and on the very right, the small material is shifted on the left. At the center (eg x = 0), the two materials are perfectly aligned.

The large material has an image texture which is sized 1000x1000. I tried downsizing it to 250x250 but it is still the same issue.

What could be wrong ? Texture wrapping ? Stretching ?

Here's some code to create the large material, model, and texture:

```
var hugeTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('hugeTexture.png'),
        hugeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: hugeTexture });

        JSONloader.load('hugeMaterial.js', function (geometry) {
            var hugeModel = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, hugeMaterial);

            hugeModel.receiveShadow = true;

            scene.add(hugeModel);
        });
```

Small materials are BoxGeometry without a texture, but just a color

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use images in power of 2 sizes. 256x256 512x512 1024x1024 etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with a 1024x1024 material but it doesn't change anything

Comment: If you haven't figured this out yet. The code we need to see is the actual texture being created and the properties being set on that texture.

Comment: can you show this part "So, I put every small material on the X-axis on the large material. (x = -5, -4, -3, etc. x = 5)."?